# TypeError: window.plugin is undefined in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am on cordova and trying to create Events in native Calander of Phone. Here is my Code. I added below code in Config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.calendar" version="4.2" />
```

and my function as below:-

```
function CreateEvent()
{
        alert("Start")
        var startDate = new Date(2014, 4, 31, 18, 30, 0, 0, 0); // beware: month 0 = january, 11 = december
        var endDate = new Date(2014, 4, 31, 19, 30, 0, 0, 0);
        var title = "Skype meeting With Lead";
        //var location = "myleads.html";
        var notes = "Need to do a skype meeting with the lead.";
        var success = function (message) { alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(message)); };
        var error = function (message) { alert("Error: " + message); };
        // window.plugins.calendar.listEventsInRange(startDate,endDate,success,error);

        //  window.plugins.calendar.createCalendar(calendarName,success,error);
        window.plugins.calendar.createEvent(title, location, notes, startDate, endDate, success, error);
        alert("End")
        alert("Sucess",success)
}
$(document).ready(function () {


        $("#btnClick").bind("click", CreateEvent,false);

});
```

but it is giving Error on click i.e `window.plugin` is undefined.

Comment: Your create event code runs inside `deviceready` listener or not ?

Answer (score 3):

What are you testing your code on?

Are you emulating an android/ios device? 
Debugging on your phone? 
Running it as localhost?

If you're not running it on a mobile device you won't have access to these plugins and their native dependencies.

For testing purposes you'll have to check whether the plugin has been loaded.

```
if (window.plugins && window.plugins.calendar) {
    window.plugins.calendar.createEvent(title, location, notes, startDate, endDate, success, error);
}
```

A list of other things you can try:

1. Run code within deviceReady listener e.g. document.addEventListener("deviceready",function() { alert('do stuff here') }, false);
2. Reinstall plugins
3. Emulate/run on an android or ios device
4. Check the plugins documentation to see if it has any other dependencies e.g. ['ngCordova'](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/)